# ¿Cómo se transforma un dataframe en un par de entrada/etiqueta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe:

```
    Do you agree    Gender  Age     City          Urban/Rural  Output
0   Yes             Female  25-34   Madrid        Urban        Will buy
1   No              Male    18-25   FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s  Rural        Won't
2   ...             ...     ...     ...      ...               Undecided
....
```

Y me gustaria transformarla en:

```
[({'Do you agree':'Yes', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': '25-34', 'City':'Madrid', 'Urban/Rural': 'Urban'}, 'Will buy'),
 ({'Do you agree':'No', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '18-25', 'City':'FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s', 'Urban/Rural': 'Rural'}, 'Won't'), ...]
```

Entonces intenté:

```
for _, row in df.iloc.iterrows():
    test = {row.keys(),row.values()}
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-257-8f1592ae7b49> in <module>
      1 for _, row in df.iloc[:,5:].iterrows():
----> 2     test = {row.keys(),row.values()}

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

## Actualizacion

Con `df.to_dict(orient = 'records')` obtengo:

```
[({'Do you agree':'Yes', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': '25-34', 'City':'Madrid', 'Urban/Rural': 'Urban', 'Output': 'Will buy'}),
 ({'Do you agree':'No', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '18-25', 'City':'FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s', 'Urban/Rural': 'Rural', 'Output': ' 'Won't''}), ...]
```

Entonces me falta la categoria que debe quedar al exterior de cada parentesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con el metodo `.to_dict()` de pandas. Tiene un atributo (`orient`) para definir como quieres el output:

> orient : str {'dict', 'list', 'series', 'split', 'records',
>   'Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.
>
> - 'dict' (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
> - 'list' : dict like {column -> [values]}
> - 'series' : dict like {column -> Series(values)}
> - 'split' : dict like {'index' -> [index], 'columns' -> [columns], 'data' -> [values]}
> - 'records' : list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]
> - 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

Por ejemplo:

### EDIT:

Modificado el ejemplo para incluir la ultima columna al final como tupla:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = [1,2,3,4], b = list('ABCD'), c = [10,20,30,40], output = ['Will buy', 'Won\'t buy', 'Will buy', 'Will buy']))
df

    a   b   c   output
0   1   A   10  Will buy
1   2   B   20  Won't buy
2   3   C   30  Will buy
3   4   D   40  Will buy

print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'a': 1, 'b': 'A', 'c': 10, 'output': 'Will buy'}, 
 {'a': 2, 'b': 'B', 'c': 20, 'output': "Won't buy"}, 
 {'a': 3, 'b': 'C', 'c': 30, 'output': 'Will buy'}, 
 {'a': 4, 'b': 'D', 'c': 40, 'output': 'Will buy'}]
```

Para incluir la ultima columna fuera del dict, primero la omitimos con un drop y luego la apendizamos al final de cada linea con zip:

```
list(zip(df.drop('output', axis=1).to_dict(orient='records'), df.output))

[({'a': 1, 'b': 'A', 'c': 10}, 'Will buy'),
 ({'a': 2, 'b': 'B', 'c': 20}, "Won't buy"),
 ({'a': 3, 'b': 'C', 'c': 30}, 'Will buy'),
 ({'a': 4, 'b': 'D', 'c': 40}, 'Will buy')]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero como guardar la categoria final al final de cada dict? `Will buy` por el primero, `won't buy` por el secundo?

Comment: Tienes razon, se me habia pasado. A ver si ahora si ;)